# Resizing layout

Tags: android, layer, aspect-ratio

1. I have one **ImageView** with **src** image;
2. It is fully **fill_parent**;
3. But the aspect ratio of the image is to be so (it does not stretch) this is good for me);

   [**ImageView** (link to image)](http://s1.postimg.org/f0wm2z44v/Screenshot_at_15_23_27_15.png)
4. How can I do so that the **layers** on top of the **ImageView** are not completely stretched and are always the size of **src** of **ImageView**;
5. For the aspect ratio is constantly adhered;

   [**Layers** (Link to Image)](http://s14.postimg.org/rv11rydfl/Screenshot_at_15_23_27_48.png)

Comment: Links for images are broken.

Comment: Didn't get what is the layer that you are talking about.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the layout xml file?

Comment: What are these "layers"? Are you trying to make portions of the image clickable like buttons?

Comment: Am want to scale views in Linear Layout or other without chang aspect ratio like in ImageView with src, how to do this?